# Android intent to check/view emails

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking for a way to fire the email-app on device from my app to check emails. Note: I do not want to 'send' any email, just want to 'check' emails. The following code crashes for the gmail app -

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.setType("message/rfc822");
          startActivity(intent);
```

The stack-trace being -

```
06-06 23:26:20.313 27703-27731/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                   Process: com.google.android.gm, PID: 27703
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
                                                       at clk.a(SourceFile:8)
                                                       at clk.loadInBackground(SourceFile:74)
                                                       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                                                       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                                                       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Is there no way to fire email app just to check emails?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL

Comment: Great! Used with makeMainSelectorActivity, and it works perfectly! Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: I didn't post an answer, in part because I have never used `makeMainSelectorActivity()` and was too lazy to go look up what that did. :-) It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397270/115145) has an example, so if that's what you used, you could accept that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the [makeMainSelectorActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method from the [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) class.

```
Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(
                     Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
                     Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email"));
```

**Intent makeMainSelectorActivity (String selectorAction, 
                String selectorCategory)**

> Make an Intent for the main activity of an application, without specifying a specific activity to run but giving a selector to find the activity. This results in a final Intent that is structured the same as when the application is launched from Home. For anything else that wants to launch an application in the same way, it is important that they use an Intent structured the same way, and can use this function to ensure this is the case.

[CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
          intent.setType("message/rfc822");
          startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this will open a dialog with all all email apps in your device. Select the app from popup and it will open.

```
try {
List<String> emailClientNames = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> emailClientPackageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
// finding list of email clients that support send email
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
    "mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
PackageManager pkgManager = AppController.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> packages = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (!packages.isEmpty()) {
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packages) {
        // finding the package name
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        emailClientNames.add(resolveInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
        emailClientPackageNames.add(packageName);
    }
    // a selection dialog  for the email clients
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Select email client");
    builder.setItems(emailClientNames.toArray(new String[]{}), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // on click we launch the right package
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(emailClientPackageNames.get(which));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Show error message
}
```

But if you want to open your default email app directly then use this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
startActivity(intent);  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.ChoseEmailClient)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Commonsware referenced

```
Intent intent= Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
startActivity(intent);
```